# Samba - releasing file lock

Tags: debian, windows, samba

Our (Windows) users are starting a program from a shared subdirectory on a Debian server. They use samba to access this directory.

When we want to release a new version of the program the started files (program file and libraries) are locked. To release these locks we restart the samba service. After restarting all locks are released and the new files can be copied to the directory.

The only disadvantage is that the users are losing all the handles to the files in all directories which are served by samba on this server. We are starting Keepass from another subdirectory and Keepass crashes afterwards.

Is there a nicer way of releasing the locks (in a single directory) ?
Is there a way to separate the samba shares ?